# WCSession: is it possible to cancel queued message?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity, wcsession

Is there any way to cancel messages sent by the `sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)` method of `WCSession`?

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/):

> Messages are queued serially and delivered in the order in which you sent them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That type of transfer is not cancellable, as

- the OS would have immediately sent any `sendMessage` data to a `reachable` counterpart

  > Use the [sendMessage] method to transfer data to a reachable counterpart. These methods are intended for immediate communication between your iOS app and WatchKit extension.
  >
  > Data sent using the [sendMessage], and `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:` methods **has a higher priority and is transmitted right away**.
- the OS provides no mechanism to specifically cancel a message

  The only `WCSession` objects that have a `cancel` method are `WCSessionUserInfoTransfer`, and `WCSessionFileTransfer`, since lower-priority `transferUserInfo` or `transferFile` data is not sent immediately, but at an optimum time determined by the OS.